# what is the ed version of times? is it timesed

Tags: grammar, mathematics

i am doing my maths revision and i was wondering how to write down the 'ed' of times.
e.g. I timesed it by 5 and it equaled 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "times" in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45590/is-it-correct-to-say-times-in-this-context)

Comment: "Times" isn't a verb.

Comment: Times is child speak for 'multiply'.

Comment: So when you are grown up enough to use the past tense, you are also old enough to say “multiplied”.

Answer (score 5):

Instead, you should use the verb"multiply" like this:
"I multiplied it by 5 and it equaled 10."